# Plunker with SystemJS and JS failed requests

Tags: javascript, systemjs, plunker

For some reason that Plunker (https://plnkr.co/edit/h56qCBpcn8lXQFckWGOT?p=preview) does not seem to properly import the jQuery using SystemJS.

**main.js**

```
import $ from 'jquery'

console.log($('body'))
```

**systemjs.config.js**

```
"jquery": "https://unpkg.com/jquery@1.12.3/dist/jquery.min.js"
```

The URL of the request have an appended **?module** that returns 404.

Someone have any idea what is wrong with Plunker? The same works just fine without Plunker.

Answer (score 1):

Experimental ES Module support was deployed to the Plunker preview server. When it was noted that this interfered with System.js it was rolled back. The linked Plunk is now working as expected.